# Overwrite variable value in yaml mapping

Tags: yaml, pyyaml

I have defined a mapping in `yaml` that looks like:

```
default: &DEFAULT
    bucket: &bucket  default_path
    # Make sure that the second parameter of join doesn't start with a / 
    # otherwise it is interpreted as an absolute path and join won't work
    path1: !!python/object/apply:os.path.join [*bucket, work_area/test1]
    path2: !!python/object/apply:os.path.join [*bucket, work_area/test2]
```

I need to define more keys where the only value to be overwritten is `bucket`, sth like:

```
production:
    <<: *DEFAULT
    bucket: "s3://production-bucket"
```

but I still get
`conf['production']['path1']` => `'default_path/work_area/test1'`
instead of
`conf['production']['path1'] => 's3://production-bucket/work_area/test1'`.
Is there any way to do this in `yaml`?

As obvious from the syntax, I use `pyyaml` to parse the file.

Comment: Which version of PyYAML are you using? With 3.10 I get a ComposerError when I try to redefine the `bucket` anchor.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I actually use 3.11 but I copy pasted the wrong case in the issue. I edited it now. When using ` bucket: &bucket "s3://production-bucket"` I also got `ComposerError`

Comment: Now you never re-define the anchor `bucket`. I think you are confusing yourself by using the same name for the mapping key as for the anchor, but the is completely irrelevant to defining an anchor (and resolving the aliases). See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

YAML interpreters should take the most recent definition of an anchor:

> An alias node is denoted by the “*” indicator. The alias refers to the most recent preceding node having the same anchor. It is an error for an alias node to use an anchor that does not previously occur in the document. It is not an error to specify an anchor that is not used by any alias node.

So even if PyYAML (3.10/3.11) would not throw a `ComposerError` if you try to parse:

```
default: &DEFAULT
    bucket: &bucket  default_path
    # Make sure that the second parameter of join doesn't start with a / 
    # otherwise it is interpreted as an absolute path and join won't work
    path1: !!python/object/apply:os.path.join [*bucket, work_area/test1]
    path2: !!python/object/apply:os.path.join [*bucket, work_area/test2]
production:
    <<: *DEFAULT
    bucket: &bucket "s3://production-bucket"
```

inserting the `path1` and `path2` keys with `<<: *DEFAULT*` would give you their expanded versions with `default_path` as that is the definition available to the parser when reading `[*bucket, work_area/test1]`

The "expansion" of the alias is done as soon as the alias is read in from the YAML source, not at some point at the end of the file, when all anchored data has been read in.

---

In you updated example, there is no other anchor `bucket` defined than the one for the scalar "`default_path`". You are confusing yourself by using the same name for the anchor and the keys (`bucket`), but the key names are completely irrelevant for resolving the alias `*bucket`.

If you can rearrange your YAML you might get something acceptable to your use case by doing ¹:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
default: &DEFAULT
    bucket: &klm default_path
production:
    &klm "s3://production-bucket"
result:
    <<: *DEFAULT
    # Make sure that the second parameter of join doesn't start with a /
    # otherwise it is interpreted as an absolute path and join won't work
    path1: !!python/object/apply:os.path.join [*klm, work_area/test1]
    path2: !!python/object/apply:os.path.join [*klm, work_area/test2]
"""

conf = ruamel.yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(conf['result']['path1'])
```

which will give you:

```
s3://production-bucket/work_area/test1
```

---

¹ This was done using [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) of which I am the author.